# Where do they get the programs that are used to learn abilities?

Tags: the-matrix

In The Matrix (live-action) movies they usually call the operator and ask for a program to learn something.

For example, Trinity asking the operator to learn how to pilot a chopper.

Where do these knowledge programs come from? And if possible to answer, how do they work?

Comment: I would like to point out that this not necessarily happens "usually". We see two examples of it in three movies, both in extreme necessity, if I recall well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The short answer: Operators steal the information they need directly from the Matrix stream of stored data used to replicate the physics of the real world and can replicate the process of information transfer the same way the Matrix does only faster.**

---

**The Longer Answer:** All information in the Matrix is stored as neural programming. Since the Matrix is designed around creating a realistic representation of the real world with real world physics models, all of the events in the Matrix are modeled including the skills used by the human minds of the Matrix.

Operators have the ability to hack the Matrix, accessing the source data where skill information is doled out to "learning minds" and steal programming, save programs outside the Matrix and upload them to the minds of their team, the same way they would be "learned" by a mind that is IN the Matrix.

The only difference is since they know it is a program, it can be force-loaded directly into their minds using the very same Matrix interface software they used while they were a part of the Matrix.

The humans of the Matrix have been neurally augmented using technology to make the matrix appear as real and as much like the real world as possible. This makes the use of "skill packages" a natural extension and advantage of creating a world where the physics and abilities of everyone have been analyzed, quantified and stored for easy access by the system (and anyone who knows where those instructions are kept).

Even new skills could be learned, stored and transferred as long as the Matrix replicated the real world conditions and could extrapolate the results based on real world physics.

Comment: No, they do not deal with it in the script or supplementary 10 DVDs. I have all of them. But since the Matrix is the source of all resources particularly of a software-driven nature, it make sense for the Zionists to steal them from the Matrix as the most effective means of getting the tools they need. They likely hack the software when necessary but I can't imagine any human writing software as complex as the is needed by the Matrix from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

In one word: **warez**.

The humans IN the Matrix have this knowledge as part of Matrix programming. Therefore, Zion people can obtain it (either programmatically, by pirating this knowledge off the Matrix, or the old fashioned way, by learning from people who know it from the Matrix - e.g. they take a helicopter flying class IN the Matrix, remember it and then save it as their own program).

I'm not aware of any canon source clarifying this, it's my own guess.

By the way, you can obtain some of that knowledge even today. Google "fm helicopter manual bell B-212" and sift carefully through results, and you will find a (likely somewhat illegal) Bell B-212 Flight Manual. Matter of fact, a B-206 manual is legitimately available from some AU government web site with Bell's permission - I wouldn't be surprised if B-212 was as well.